# OCaml toplevel output formatting

Tags: ocaml

If I execute the following in OCaml's toplevel:

```
#require "num";;
open Ratio;;

ratio_of_int 2;;
```

The output is:

```
- : Ratio.ratio = <ratio 2/1>
```

How's a formatting like this possible? The [sources](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/ocaml/trunk/otherlibs/num/ratio.ml?rev=9547&view=markup) tell me that Ratio.ratio is a record. So the output should be more akin to

```
{numerator = <big_int 2>; denominator = <big_int 1>; normalized = true}
```

I tried see if ratio output is somehow hardcoded in toplevel, but this search was fruitless. Being new to OCaml, I must ask if I'm missing something important? In a language that has overloaded stringification funcs this wouldn't be strange, but in OCaml's case I find this behavior quite out of place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Findlib has a pretty printer specifically for the ratio module.  Instead of printing out `<abstr>` (the interface doesn't expose the record), it prints out what you saw.  If you want to check it out, look at findlib/num_top_printers.ml:

```
let ratio_printer fmt v =
  Format.fprintf fmt "<ratio %s>" (Ratio.string_of_ratio v)
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured this out while pondering your (now deleted) question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I was confused at first because I didn't have findlib installed on my computer at work.  I knew it was due to a pretty printer but didn't know where the pretty printer was located at until I realized that it was findlib.

Comment: Seems like using [custom pretty printers in toplevel](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html#toc90) is quite easy.

Comment: Yet, I think using pretty printers is just a hack around the frustrating limitation in OCaml that functions can't be overloaded.

Comment: In case the URL changes again, documentation for [custom pretty printers in the toplevel](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/5.0/htmlman/toplevel.html#s%3Atoplevel-directives) is found in OCaml Manual 14.2

Answer (score 5):

The toplevel has a directive `#install_printer`, that takes a function to print any type.

For example, you can redefine how to print integers like this:

```
let print_integer ppf n = Format.fprintf ppf "Integer(%d)" n
#install_printer print_integer
```

`#install_printer` chooses printers depending on the type of the function given as argument (here, `Format.formatter -> int -> unit`).