# Why are rational numbers from Num printed as <abstr>?

Tags: ocaml, arbitrary-precision, opam, rational-number

I continue with my exploration on the `Num` library of Ocaml, with the reason that one whole library about logics was written using it.

Today, I would like to make the negative of a rational number. Obtain `-1/2`, from `1/2`.

To do so, I think that, given an `a` of type `Ratio.ratio`, I can compute the negative of it (and return a `ratio`, not a `num`) this way:

`ratio_of_num (minus_num (num_of_ratio a))`

(Functions from: https://ocaml.org/releases/4.05/htmlman/libref/Num.html#TYPEnum)

Now, I would like to check the result, but I always get this solution: `Ratio.ratio = <abstr>`

The point is that now I realize that I always get this solution when I use `ratio_of_num`. For instance:

```
ratio_of_num (Int 2);;
- : Ratio.ratio = <abstr>
```

I have searched a bit and found this question ([OCaml toplevel output formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453853/ocaml-toplevel-output-formatting)) where a different function (`ratio_of_int 2`) was used, but seems no longer possible. Maybe that `ratio` is a different library.

Any help?

PS: By the way, in order to replace `num` in the future, I am trying to install `Zarith` with `opam`, but cannot.

My problem is I do `opam install zarith` and this is displayed:

```
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build conf-gmp 3
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed

The packages you requested declare the following system dependencies. Please
make sure they are installed before retrying:
    gmp
```

So I do `opam install gmp` and I get:

```
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build gmp 6.2.1
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed
```

Which offers me no clue on how to continue trying. Any help with this also?

I would appreciate any answer whether for the first question or the second one!!

Here below, I post some editions that have been added to the question, as a result of the conversation below:

EDIT (Solved adding the needed #require)

I have done what @ivg has suggested, but still does not work (I do the initial `open Num`, because it will ask it otherwise):

```
─( 23:12:59 )─< command 0 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # open Num;;
─( 23:13:00 )─< command 1 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # let pp_num ppf x = Format.fprintf ppf "%s" (Num.string_of_num x);;
val pp_num : Format.formatter -> num -> unit = <fun>
─( 23:14:11 )─< command 2 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # #install_printer pp_num;;
─( 23:14:16 )─< command 3 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # ratio_of_num (Int 2);;
- : Ratio.ratio = <abstr>
```

EDIT 2 (Also needed a #require)

I have also tried Ocaml instead of utop, but the error is worse:

```
        OCaml version 4.10.2

Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable threads

# open Num;;
# let pp_num ppf x = Format.fprintf ppf "%s" (Num.string_of_num x);;
Error: Reference to undefined global `Num'
#
```

EDIT 3 (Works in Ocaml, instead of utop)

```
##require "num";;
# let pp_num ppf x = Format.fprintf ppf "%s" (Num.string_of_num x);;
val pp_num : Format.formatter -> Num.num -> unit = <fun>
# #install_printer pp_num;;
# ratio_of_num (Int 2);;
- : Ratio.ratio = <ratio 2/1>
#
```

EDIT 4 (Works in utop, note that printing simplifies the result when it is an integer)

```
utop # let pp_ratio ppf r = Format.fprintf ppf "%a" pp_num (num_of_ratio r);;
val pp_ratio : Format.formatter -> Ratio.ratio -> unit = <fun>
─( 23:28:07 )─< command 6 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # #install_printer pp_ratio;;
─( 23:28:22 )─< command 7 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # ratio_of_num (Int 2);;
- : Ratio.ratio = 2
─( 23:28:29 )─< command 8 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop #
```

Comment: I’ll have to mention this is the 6,666th question with tag [ocaml]. Congrats!

Comment: Whoa, thanks! jejeje

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you have `<abstr>` instead of the actual representation is that the top-level (aka interpreter) doesn't know how to print the `num` object. It is easy to teach the top-level, using the `#install_printer` directive, e.g.,

```
let pp_num ppf x = Format.fprintf ppf "%s" (Num.string_of_num x);;
val pp_num : Format.formatter -> Num.num -> unit = <fun>
# #install_printer pp_num;;
# ratio_of_num (Int 2);;
- : Ratio.ratio = <ratio 2/1>
#
```

So we defined the pretty-printing function,

```
let pp_num ppf x = Format.fprintf ppf "%s" (Num.string_of_num x)
```

And then used the `#install_printer` directive to install it in the top-level,

```
# #install_printer pp_num;;
```

and now every time we have `num` it will be printed for us.

You can also use this `pp_num` function together with other `Format` module functions (that are used for pretty printing), e.g.,

```
Format.printf "my num = %a" pp_num (ratio_of_num (Int 2))
```

It might be that an older version of OCaml is unable to derive how to print ratio from the nums itself, so we can help it by defining an additional printer,

```
# let pp_ratio ppf r = Format.fprintf ppf "%a" pp_num (num_of_ratio r);;
val pp_ratio : Format.formatter -> Ratio.ratio -> unit = <fun>
# #install_printer pp_ratio;;
# ratio_of_num (Int 2);;
- : Ratio.ratio = 2
```

Re: P.S.

For zarith you need to install system dependencies. You can use opam for that, e.g.,

```
opam depext --install zarith
```

it will install the system dependencies (the `gmp` library) using your operating system package manager and then install the zarith library.

Comment: Hi! It makes sense, so a pretty printer is needed. The point is I have made what you said, and the problem still remains.. I do the same and then (look my EDIT on the initial question).

Comment: that is strange, can you try `ocaml` instead of `utop`? It also could be that your OCaml is very old... what version are you using?

Comment: If I do it in Ocaml, you can see the response in the EDIT2 . I also ask ```which ocaml``` and responds ```4.10.2``` so... (I really thank your help, by the way!)

Comment: Well, I can only suggest adding a yet another printer, this time specifically for the ratio type. The post is updated.

Comment: responsing to edit2 : you need to do `#require "num";;`  before anything else

Comment: Okay so. 1) In Ocaml it works (I have put the require), I put it in a new EDIT 3 so that you can see it (and after that I will make the question more readable) 2) The second way (the new printer), you can see it in EDIT 4. It works, but, prints 2 instead of 2/1. And last but no least, thanks again. I would like to appreciate all this help, but I do not see any way to pay for a coffee on your profile :)

Comment: The new printing is fine, it is just the new function not only prints but simplifies the expression, try for example ` div_num (Int 3) (Int 5)` and `div_num (Int 10) (Int 5)`, they will be printed as `3/5` and `2` correspondingly.

Comment: and you're welcome) Saying thanks is more than enough)